# How to Split a string: get n characters, skip n characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get n characters from a string, skip n characters and get n characters etc.  I shoudl start getting the characters from the number n until the end of the string:

```
e.g.
n = 2
string = helloworld!
result = elwod!
```

my actual string is a binary string `"0010100"`. I tried with this:

```py
check = 1
while check <= len(newstring):
    i = check
    checkbits = ''
    for i in range(1,len(newstring)+1,i*2):
        checkbits += newstring[i-1:i:i]
    print(checkbits)
    check *= 2
    print()
```

and my output is:

```
0110

01

0
```

instead of the expected:

```
0110
0100
0100
```

I think there is something wrong here: `newstring[i-1:i:i]` but I can't figure out what :(

**---- Thank you everyone for your answers ----**

I don't know if it can be useful but since with this answer I was able to finish my (one function) binary hamming encoder, I add the link here: [LINK](https://github.com/fabiom91/hamming_encode/blob/master/hamming_encode_function.py)

I used Austin code from line 30 to 40 (and also part of it somewhere else in the code) :)

Comment: in your example with `helloworld!`, the output should start from `ll`, so I am confused

Comment: no, is right, because you should count from 1, not from 0 as instead python indexes the string characters

Comment: not sure what you mean, since python is 0 indexed

Comment: @aws_apprentice, for the problem, `n=2` means start at second letter, 3 means start at third letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop to iterate over indices, form list and join at the end:

```
n = 2
string = 'helloworld!'

lst = []
for i in range(n-1, len(string), 2*n):
    lst.append(string[i:i+n])

print(''.join(lst))
# elwod!
```

Comment: Thank you Austin!! :D
Now I have my Hamming encoder working xD